# Cannot fetch records from sql server table

Tags: apache-nifi

I cannot fetch record from sql server database table. I have warining mentioned below. I also added steps i did. Please of help.

What i did was:

```
1. Nifi installed
2. JDBC driver downloaded and placed into C drive.
3. Created processor "QueryDatabasetable"
4. In Database Connection Poling  Service i configured:
   Database Connection URL:  jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=MyDb
   Database driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
   Database Location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC DRIVER 7.2 for SQL Server\mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre8.jar
   Database user: xxx
   Database password: xxx

   Database Type: MS SQL 2010+
   Table name: T_Items
   Columns to return: Price
```

Once this processor is created i have yellow warning mark saying:

> "Database Connection Pooling service validated against  is
>   invalid because Controller Service with ID  is disabled

Answer (score 4):

Once you configure DBCPConnectionPool then **`enable`** the DBCPConnectionPool by clicking on the button next to gear.

- Once we enable the connection pool then it shows state as **`Enabled`**
  [image]